# Returning an array of structs from a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am working on an API for a client. They wanted it in the CVI environment for their project. It's essencially a parser. So we are aiming to create a .h and .C file that has a function in it that can be called so they can parse a file and read each of the elements in a .csv file. Each line will be separated and placed in a variable in a struct that is an element in an array of structs.

I've developed the function. now I want to get the function to handle two arguments: an array with the filepath string stored in it, and the number of lines to read.

so it essentially was a function that had a void type.

```
void ParseConfigFile(char filepath[], int LinesToRead);
```

I have the struct decleration defined in the header file.

I then declared:

```
struct TestStep TestSteps[500];
```

During debugging I was just able to print at the bottom of the function using a format like:

```
TestSteps[LineNumber].StructElement
```

easily.

How do i convert it into a function that can be called with the arguments shown above and return the array of structs so the user can just call:

```
TestSteps[LineNumber].StructElement
```

I hope that wasn't confusing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `struct TestStep[] ParseConfigFile(char filepath[], int LinesToRead)`?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible ways to get the data from the file.

The first is to have the client provide the array of structs. Then pass that array and its length to the function. The function may not fill the whole array, maybe because there are fewer entries or because the file can't be opened. Return the actual length of the array or an error indicator, typically `-1`:

```
int read_config(const char *filepath,
    struct config cfg[], int max_cfg);
```

and call it like this:

```
struct config cfg[MAX_CONFIG];
int n;

n = read_config("my.config", cfg, MAX_CONFIG);
if (n > 0) {
    // configure!
}
```

This is probably close to your "lines to read" approach.

The second is to return a list of configurations that your function allocates on the heap with `malloc` and/or `realloc`:

```
struct config *new_config(const char *filepath);
```

Then you must find a means to signal how many configurations were read. You can do this with a sentinel value, usually a `NULL` pointer in one of your struct fields. Alternatively, you can write this information to a variable that the user must supply:

```
struct config *new_config(const char *filepath, size_t &nconfig);
```

Because this information was allocated, the user must `free` it. A typical use case is:

```
struct config *cfg;
size_t n;

cfg = new_config("my.config", &n);
if (cfg) {
    // configure!

    free(cfg);
}
```

This approach is more flexible, because it allows for an arbitrary number of configuration settings. But it is a bit harder to code and to use.